# How to turn on headed mode in Playwright when headless=False doesnt work?

Tags: playwright

**Problem Context**

I'm trying to launch Playwright in headed mode in Python.

Despite setting headless=False I still can't launch a browser

**Existing Code**

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=100)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto("https://www.google.com/")
```

Output

```
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.686 seconds
```

**Debugging Methods I've tried already**

1)Going to terminal "$env:HEADED=1"

2)Going to terminal "$env:PWDEBUG=1"

3)Using firefox and webkit instead of chromium

4)Using a Pycharm setup instead of Microsoft Visual Studio Code

I'd appreciate any thoughts of alternative solutions please.
Thanks in advance

Comment: As per the documents, your code seems correct. I would suggest trying with a different version of playwright to see if it works then. Also, try using false instead of False. I doubt if that makes a difference but could be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

try adding --headed in running test command line: npx playwright test --headed

Comment: Thanks that looks like a node JS solution your suggestion. What I found is need to go to terminal pytest --headed in addition to the script i put above. Thanks for the inspiration